# spl_autoload server related issue

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register, spl-autoloader

We seem to have a very strange problem with the spl_autoload on 1 particular servers.
Warning: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Unable to access file.php

```
public function loadClass($className) {

        if(substr($className, -5) == 'Override') {

            $classes = glob(_ROOT_DIR_ . 'classes/*/override/*/*.php');

            foreach($classes AS $class) {
                $explodePath = explode('/', $class);
                $explodePath = array_reverse($explodePath);

                if(file_exists(_ROOT_DIR_.'classes/'.$explodePath[3].'/override/'.$explodePath[1].'/'.$explodePath[0])) {
                    set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR._ROOT_DIR_.'classes/'.$explodePath[3].'/override/'.$explodePath[1].'/');
                    spl_autoload(strtolower($className));
                }
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Also I have checked and in our WHM panel it shows the include path is set to 
.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php

This particular server is Linux RedHat-9.3.6 running PHP 5.3.8 & eAccelerator
the code above has been testing on 10 other servers and works fine so really at lost to why this would be happening on this particular server.

We would really like to use the spl_autoload method instead of include/require which would slow down our application.
Please I hope someone can offer some advice with helping us to solve this issue.

Comment: Does other servers also run with eAccelerator / APC ?

Comment: No this is the only one running eAccelerator.

Comment: So you may try disabling it to see if it helps

Comment: same error even with disabling eAccelerator :(

Comment: We were hoping someone could at least advice us in resolving this issue.